# How can I get the current Projects & Solutions directory from the settings in VS 2017 and load solution using SDK?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-sdk

I've built a custom tool window extension for VS 2017. Everything works except for 2 things:

I need to get the "Projects location" from Tools/Options/Projects and Solutions/Locations.

I also need to tell the current instance of VS to load a solution or project.

I have been searching for days on the VS SDK, and haven't been able to come up with much.  I got this far:

```
ShellSettingsManager sm = new ShellSettingsManager();
```

But that needs one of two interfaces as a parameter, IVsSettingsManager or IServiceProvider.

I implement the interface and of course, it creates the methods, all coded with NotImplemented exceptions.

So since I'm totally clueless here, I hope someone can point me in the right direction, if not just outright show me how to do it.

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of all this?  You may simply be approaching a problem from the wrong angle.  I only ask because you say you want the projects folder (I assume the default folder) and then you'll open a solution, so I also assume you're making an assumption about project locations, which isn't a good idea.  Give us an outline of the extension and it may help clarify.

Comment: We have an internal code repository. This extension allows a developer to check out and check in code for a project. The requirement is that when code is checked out from the repository, it is placed in a folder inside the defined projects location. Before you ask, we are a small group of 3 devs and we are not allowed to use a 3rd party tool for this (TFS/Git). Our request to purchase a license was denied and using freeware/open source is prohibited.

Comment: Can you not define the root project folder with a setting, rather than trying to find the default VS project folder?

Comment: I could, but why would I need to?  The SDK is there, i'm just looking for assistance in figuring out how to use this specific part of it.

Comment: It's obviously up to you, but 2 days spent over something that could be done in 5 minutes, and it's still not resolved?  I'll leave you to it.  Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured this out. There is a ServiceProvider you can provide to the constructor for the ShellSettingsManager. All the examples i've seen just used:

```
SettingsManager sm = new ShellSettingsManager(ServiceProvider);
```

But when I tried that, I got "ServiceProvider is a type, which is not valid in the given context"

I finally found an example that used:

```
SettingsManager sm = new ShellSettingsManager(ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider);
```

That same example then went on...

```
SettingsStore ss = sm.GetReadOnlySettingsStore(SettingsScope.UserSettings);
```

Here is where I had to figure the rest out for myself.

There are two enumerables in the SettingsStore, GetPropertyNames and GetSubCollectionNames.  These are helpful to find the collection and property I need.  So first I did this:

```
        string msg = "";
        foreach (string s in ss.GetPropertyNames(""))
        {
            msg += s + "\r\n";
        }
        MessageBox.Show(msg);
```

The empty string as the parameter gets the root collection properties, and this had what I need.

[image: screenshot of messagebox]

So now I finally retrieved the value I needed.

```
string DefaultNewProjectLocation = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(ss.GetString("", "DefaultNewProjectLocation"));
```

The first parameter, the empty string, is the root collection, and the 2nd parameter is the property I want.  It returned:

```
%USERPROFILE%\source\repos
```

Expanding the environment variable gives me the literal path.

Now on to figuring out how to get the current instance of VS to load a project selected in my tool window.

Edit: After another full day of searching, finally got Visual Studio to load a project in the instance which my extension is running. Several people had told me to use Process.Start and pass the path to the solution file but this started another instance of Visual Studio and loaded it there.

I found the DTE.ExecuteCommand(string Command, string Args) but didn't know if that would be what I needed. Then I read something that said it executes commands available in the Tools/Options/Environment/Keyboard section.  I perused through there and found "File.OpenProject" and figured I could send the solution file as the argument. But there was one more problem in the way...

Adding a reference to EnvDTE and trying this:

```
DTE.ExecuteCommand("File.OpenProject", "\"" + PathToSlnFile + "\"");
```

Just gave me an error that said,

> an object reference is required for the non-static field, method or
>   Property '_DTE.ExecuteCommand(string, string)'

I tried instantiating it

```
var dte = new DTE();
```

But that just gave me some runtime error about not being able to read something about the COM library.  I found a million examples of using DTE.ExecuteCommand but not one of them showed how to get a reference to it. I did find this in Google Books, "Mastering Visual Studio .NET: Getting the Most Out of the Visual Studio .NET Environment"

> The way in which you obtain a reference to the DTE object will depend
>   on what type of code you are writing.  Macros just use a global
>   variable provided by the macro environment called DTE. Add-ins are
>   passed a reference to this object when VS.NET initializes them.

Ok, that still doesn't tell me anything. How do I get that reference?!?

And then I got lucky. I finally stumbled across a random page (i'd link it but I closed it already and don't think I could ever find it again).  It gave me what I needed.

```
private DTE dte = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(DTE)) as DTE;
```

And now, I can do this, and it works a treat!

```
dte.ExecuteCommand("File.OpenProject", "\"" + PathToSolutionFile + "\"");
```

Hopefully this will save some other poor slob like me from spending three full days searching and finding nothing on their foray into writing a Visual Studio Extension.